# iPhone: how to pass data back and forth between Parent view controller and Detail View controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iphone app which has a Parent view controller with some data. I tap on one of the rows and push a Detail VC on to the stack, where I want to edit the parent's data. When I pop the Detail view, the Parent view should see the changed data.

What's the simplest and nicest way of achieving this? I know I can: a) go up the view controller chain and edit the Parent's data directly (- messy), b) use delegates to callback when popping the Details view (- cumbersome), c) send notifications (- too much work).

There has to be something simpler, possibly using properties to pass in the exact same pointer from the Parent view to the Detail view, so that the detail view acts on the same exact data as the Parents? This way, the Detail view doesn't have to do anything when it's popped off the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, its called model-view-controller. You really want your data to be stored into another class, called the model. Objects that need to know about changes to the model should be informed of changes to it, which can be done with key value observing or delegation. In this case, your parent view controller would subscribe to changes in the model. When the data changed, the parent view controller could become notified, and refresh his table. If the parent isn't currently visible, you could suspend these updates and refresh the parent when it becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

In a project I am working on right now I created a class called "DataServices".  The DataServices object is instantiated only once during "applicationDidFinishLaunching":

```
ds = [[DataServices alloc] init];
ds.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[ds initialize_data];
```

Any module that needs data declares something like:

```
extern DataServices *ds;
```

...and is free to access the common app data as required.  Read. Write. Modify.  The abstraction is complete.  I could do anything I want to the encoding, storage and source of the data and the interface to the various modules requiring data services would not change.  Works fine for what I am doing.  Perhaps this could work for you.

As far as detecting changes from class to class.  I have a flag in DataServices called "modified".  This flag is cleared prior to, for example, displaying a new view controller that could make changes.  Any of the "set" or "update" member functions in DataServices will set this flag.  With this:

```
if(ds.modified)
{
// Do what you have to do if data is modified
}
```

Flags could be set for groups of settings as required, you don't necessarily need to have a single one-size-fits-all modified flag.  Flags can also be complex.  You could have a flag that only triggers if specific data reached thresholds, etc.